# React and CSS Transitions, am I missing something?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

Am I missing something in this code example below:

What I want: I want the component to render in with a fade effect and render out with a fade out effect.

What I get: The component renders instantly.

```
// Overlay.jsx
const Overlay: React.FC<{isOpen: boolean, onClickOverlay: React.MouseEventHandler> = ({
  isOpen,
  onClickOverlay,
}: any) => {
  const overlayClasses = classnames({
    drawer__overlay: true,
    drawer__overlay__open: isOpen,
    drawer__overlay__closed: !isOpen,
  });
  return isOpen 
    ? (<div
          onClick={onClickOverlay}
          className={overlayClasses}
        />
      ) 
    : null;
}

// Overlay.scss
.drawer {
  &__overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    &__open {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    &__closed {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

My working theory on this is that the CSS isn't transitioning because the component is being mounted/unmounted.  But not sure how to do this.  I should let you know using react-transition-group has been a complete bust for me, so if you suggest that, please provide some examples.

Comment: Is the component first mounted with `isOpen` set to false, and then `isOpen` is set to true subsequently? The element needs to be rendered to the page for at least one frame with the opacity set to 0 or else CSS transitions won't work for transitioning it to a new value - it will instantly render with the "final" value.

Comment: Yes.  "isOpen" is a prop.  I'm thinking some sort of componentWillMount() componentWillUnmount() (but with hooks) solution here?